# How do you scale down an ImageView with ObjectAnimator, but have it retain its position in layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to scale an ImageView down in an animation, but whenever I do so it appears to shift down and to left in the layout. Here is a screenshot before I animate:

[image: before animation]

And here what it looks like after the animation:

[image: after animation]

Is it possible to have the ImageView scale down, but have its top-left corner remain in the top-left corner of the layout?

Here is the code I am using:

```
// ScaleTestActivity.java

import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ScaleTestActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView mImageView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "scaleX", 0.5f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "scaleY", 0.5f);

        scaleDownX.setDuration(1000);
        scaleDownY.setDuration(1000);

        AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();

        scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);
        scaleDown.start();
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
<!-- main.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:src="@drawable/droid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The drawable resource:

[image: Large Android Logo]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try to set your view's pivotX and pivotY to 0. Scaling is done from that point. I think it will work fine.